# Change the version of a project in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I have a project with a sonar-project.properties file. This file had up to now the version `sonar.projectVersion=trunk` and every time, the project was scanned by SonarQube, it was saved in SonarQube as version `trunk`.

Is it now possible to change the version in SonarQube to another version? So, change the version of the code which is alredy scanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SonarQube, click your project, then 'Activity' tab. On the left panel you will see all versions. Click little pencil icon next to your version to change it.

Comment: How to switch version then?